# Why is there a yellow solution formed upon reaction of silicon tetrachloride with water?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

I've read somewhere that reacting the two will give a white solid and a yellow solution. I'm assuming the white solid is the silicon dioxide, but what is the chemical origins of the yellow colour of the solution?

Comment: How pure is the used SiCl4? There is chance there is dissolved FeCl3 impurity, forming yellow ferric chloride solution.

Comment: I don't have information on its purity, but I suspect you may be right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The yellow color is indeed due to an impurity. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_tetrachloride):

> Silicon tetrachloride is prepared by the chlorination of various silicon compounds such as ferrosilicon, silicon carbide, or mixtures of silicon dioxide and carbon. The ferrosilicon route is most common.[[1](https://doi.org/10.1002/14356007.a24_001)]

Thus the most likely impurities are chlorine and iron, the latter converted to ferric chloride by the chlorination process. Either one may produce a yellow color in water solution.

**Cited Reference**

1. Simmler, W. "Silicon Compounds, Inorganic". *Ullmann's Encyclopedia of Industrial Chemistry*. Weinheim: Wiley-VCH. doi:10.1002/14356007.a24_001